# mysql insert/update always inserting never updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to insert if a row doesn't exist with the given part_code or update if the part_code already exists. The problem is that it always inserts and produces duplicates. Can anyone see why.

```
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM qty_csv';  
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if (!$result) {
    die(mysqli_error($conn));
}   
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $part_code          = $row['code'];
    $part_descr         = $row['descr'];
    $part_qty_in_stock  = $row['qty_in_stock'];
    $reorder_level      = $row['reorder_level'];
    $reorder_qty        = $row['reorder_qty'];
    $part_price         = $row['price'];

        // check to see if the value you are entering is already there      
        $result1 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM part WHERE part_code == '$part_code'");
        if (!$result1){ 
            $sql = 
                    "INSERT INTO part  VALUES (
                            '',
                            '',
                            '$part_descr',
                            '$part_price',
                            '',
                            '$part_code',
                            '',
                            '',
                            '',
                            '',
                            '$reorder_level',
                            '$reorder_qty',
                            '',
                            '',
                            '$part_qty_in_stock',
                            '',
                            '',
                            ''
                            )";
            if (!$conn->query($sql)) {
                echo "INSERT failed: (' . $conn->errno . ') " . $conn->error;
            }    
        }else{
            $sql = "UPDATE part SET "
                    . "part_qty_in_stock    = '$part_qty_in_stock',"
                    . "reorder_level        = '$reorder_level',"
                    . "reorder_qty          = '$reorder_qty' "
                    . "WHERE part_code == '$part_code'";
            // This code exists and will be updated
            $conn->query($sql);
        }    
  }
```

I have it under the debugger and see that even if `part_code == '$part_code'` the `$result1` is bool()false. I would have expected it to be true.

Comment: Take out a `=` in `WHERE part_code == '$part_code'` that shouldn't be there. This is not PHP, but SQL. Those are *two seperate animals* altogether.

Comment: Fred is right plus you should read on `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause...

Comment: Thanks @MarcellFülöp, I found that `ON DUPLICATE KEY ` to be useful and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your "$result1" object is False only when an error happens, otherwise, even if the query returns no results (because it's empty), it will be a mysqly object.

You should  check the number of rows rather than just checking !$result.

Just change

```
if (!$result1){
```

with

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) == 0){
```

Check out the docs for more info:

https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I also have to thank Fred and others who reminded me of the == and mithredate had a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

please check your query,please use `=` for checking instead of  `==`

```
SELECT * FROM part WHERE part_code = '$part_code'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$result1 = $conn->query("SELECT count(*) as count FROM part WHERE part_code = '$part_code'");
```

Then simply check `$result1['count'] > 0`